# How to tell the Task Scheduler MMC to remember the column widths of the History?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, task-scheduler, windows

Using the Task Scheduler MMC on a Windows Server 2008 R2, I'm facing something that is very annoying to me:

The History window of a task does not remember the column widths, thus making it rather difficult/impossible to read.

**Example:**

This is how it looks initially, when opening the MMC and selecting one task:

[image]

I then adjust the column widths by double-clicking and can finally read the content:

[image]

Then, I select another task and face the same (too small) columns again:

[image]

This is really driving me nuts. Since I'm a developer and only a "part-time administrator", I cannot imagine how a full time administrator can use this tool without getting insane.

**So my question is:**

Is there a way to configure the Windows Task Scheduler MMC to remember the widths of the columns of the History window?

(Alternatively: Is there another GUI tool to manage my Scheduled Tasks?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not start Task Scheduler with AutoIT (or something similar).  Write a little script where the very fist thing it does upon startup is fix up your columns.

Normally you'd have trouble getting consistent coordinates for the column locations, but given the fact that the columns always default to the first size, it actually makes your life easier as far as AutoIT goes.

Comment: So Microsoft expects each user to write an AutoIt script to adjust columns?   While this answer is not technically wrong, I do think it is a bit unreasonable.   An alternate Task Scheduler history reader or an ability to make column width changes stick would be more appropriate.

Comment: Yes you are right, it is unreasonable.  But since I don't work for Microsoft, it's no use complaining to me about it.